# Form won't open in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm using Sharepoint Designer (2010) to develop a series of connected lists.

I have a number of child-lists and I use the "DispForm.aspx" of my main list to add these 'children'.

Recently the DispForm.aspx has stopped opening in Sharepoint Designer. Clicking it from the list's main page goes into the Form view, but the page never loads and I get no error messages.

Since I can't see the Code window I can't make any changes, even though the page works fine in the browser and I can perform (limited) edits directly on the website through Sharepoint.

Has anyone got any tips on what I could try, or any way of accesing the code in DispForm.aspx if I can't open it in Sharepoint Designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a fix as such, but I got around this by mapping a drive to the sharepoint site and using notepad++ to edit the file directly.

If you browse the lists folder and the list you are interested in you will see the display, new, edit forms in there

S

Comment: Thanks. This almost works(!). 
When I open an aspx file in Notepad++ I get some code, but it's not the same as I get in SharepointDesigner (for instance comparing DispForm.aspx from another list with what's in SD there's a lot of code that isn't shown... my own HTML and javascript editions among them).